# How to detect the description of spine segments in short text using a neural network?

Tags: natural-language-processing

The input data is a set of text chunks containing the description of the pathology or the surgical procedure:

For instance:

1. Tere is a lumbar stenosis L3/4
2. Patient ist suffering from [...], MRI and X ray showed lumbar stenosis L3/4, segmental instability L3-5, foraminal stenosis L5/S1 both sides
3. The patient [...] underwent an MRI showing cervical stenosis C4-7 with myelopathy
4. [...] showed lumbar adult scoliosis L2-S1 with Cobb angle of 42°
5. Patient fell from the chair [...] showed osteoporotic fracture L3

Now, the ideal classificator would give me:

1. Segments: L3,L4; typeofpathology: degenerative; subtypepathology: stenosis
2. Segments: L3,L4,L5,S1; type of pathology: degenerative; subtypepathology: stenosis, instability
3. Segments C4, C5, C6, C7;type of pathology: degenerative; subtypepathology: myelopathy
4. Segments L2,L3,L4,L5,S1;type of pathology: deformity; subtypepathology: de novo scoliosis
5. Segments L3; type of pathology: pathological fracture; subtypepathology: -

I think that this cannot be reasonably achieved by a pre-programmed algorithm, because the amount of the text before the description can vary, and the choice of words can vary too. Is there an approach using neural networks or NLP tools that would have chance at reaching such classification? How large would the dataset used for training have to be (approximately)?

Maybe it would be reasonable to separate the two problems: detection of the segments AND detection of the pathology. For the segments, one could search for a pattern of C? T? L? or S? with ? being a number and then include all such segment descriptions in the next 20-30 characters, then use an algorithm to mark the continuous segments from the upper to the lower vertebra.

Done this, do neural networks offer any significant advantages over simple keyword matching classification? Most importantly, which NLP neural network tools would be the ones you would start trying with?